# MusixTex problem with format

Tags: musixtex

I have problem with Musixtex formating. I have this:

[image]

but I need this (only 3 rows):

[image]

here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixlyr}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Vyletěla holubička}
\begin{music}
\nostartrule
\setlength\parindent{0pt}%
\instrumentnumber{1} % a single instrument
\nobarnumbers
\setlyrics{text}{Vy-le-tě-la ho-lu-bič-ka ze ská-ly, ze ská-ly, pro-bu-di-la mo-dré o-či ze spa-ní  pro-bu-di-la mo-dré o-či ze spa-ní. }
\generalmeter{\meterfrac24} % 2/4 meter chosen
\scale{1.0}
\assignlyrics1{text}

\normalmusicsize

\startpiece
\Notes\Qqbu cdef\en\bar
\Notes\Qqbu ghig\en\bar
\NOTes\qa{jj}\en\bar
\NOTEs\ha{i}\en\bar
\NOTes\qa{hh}\en\bar
\NOTEs\ha{g}\en
\endpiece

\startpiece
\Notes\Qqbu fhfd\en
\bar
\Notes\Qqbu egec\en
\bar
\NOTes\qa{dd}\en
\bar
\NOTEs\ha{g}\en
\endpiece

\startpiece
\Notes\Qqbu fhfd\en
\bar
\Notes\Qqbu egec\en
\bar
\NOTes\qa{dd}\en
\bar
\NOTEs\ha{c}\en
\Endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

Please, help.

Answer (score 5):

After the first run of (pdf)LaTeX you need to run `musixflx`

```
musixflx filename
```

(where `filename` is the name of the main TeX file, without extension). Then run (pdf)LaTeX again.

[image]

Comment: @egreg +1 for your wonderful work. it is very nice.