# Converting PMX preprocessed MusiXTeX code to proper LaTeX code

Tags: music, musixtex, pmx

I want to include a MusiXTeX script into a normal LaTeX document, in order to be able to add another piece of music to the same output pdf document (which will be one DIN A4 page).

When working only with MusiXTeX, the scripts won't contain a `\documentclass` (e.g. `{scrartcl}`) or a `\begin{document}`, whereas some commands from MusiXTeX seem to be unnecessary when loading MusiXTeX into LaTeX as a package (`\usepackage{musixtex}`) (I think this holds true for the `\input` commands) or even error causing (such as `\nopagenumbers` or `\bye`).

Let's take the following PMX preprocessed MusiXTeX code as an example:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Saabund.tex
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input musixtex
\input pmx
\setmaxslurs{24}\setmaxinstruments{24}%
\normalmusicsize%
\nopagenumbers
\tracingstats=2\relax
\hsize=524pt
\vsize740pt
\def\nbinstruments{1}
\setstaffs11
\setclef10
\setname1{ }
\generalsignature{-1}%
\generalmeter\meterC%
\parindent 0pt
\elemskip1pt\afterruleskip1.000pt\beforeruleskip0pt\relax
\stafftopmarg0pt\staffbotmarg5\Interligne\interstaff{10}\relax
\nostartrule
\readmod{Saabund}
\nobarnumbers%
\input musixlyr %
\startmuflex\startpiece\addspace\afterruleskip%
\global\parskip 0pt plus 12\Interligne minus 99\Interligne%
\def\upstrut{\znotes&\zcharnote{\upamt}{~}\en}%
\znotes\zcharnote{16}{\titles{2.0}{}{0}%
{Saabund on j\"{a}lle \"{o}\"{o}}{2.0}{}{0}}\en%
% Bar count 1
\starteq%
\pnotes{4.00}%
\pmxlyr{Saa-bund on j\"{a}-lle \"{o}\"{o}, mis mei-le t\"{a}h-te-de vaik-set ra-hu toob.}\spread{-6}%
\hu f\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\qu f\qu f\en%
% Bar count 2
\xbar
\pnotes{3.46}\qup g\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\cu{'a}\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\pcaesura00\qu f\qu f\en%
% Bar count 3
\xbar
\pnotes{3.46}\qlp{'b}\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\cl{'c}\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\qu{'a}\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\ibu1f2\qb1f\tbu1\qb1{'a}\en%
% Bar count 4
\alaligne
\pnotes{2.00}\spread{-6}\ibu1g{-1}\qb1{'a}\qb1{`g}\qb1f\tbu1\qb1e\en%
\pnotes{4.00}\pcaesura00\hu f\en%
% Bar count 5
\xbar
\pnotes{4.00}%
\pmxlyr{L\~{o}pp-e-nud p\"{a}ev-a-t\"{o}\"{o} ja puh-ke-aeg ta-sa v\"{a}rs-keid j\~{o}u-de koob.}%
\hu{'a}\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\qu{'a}\qu a\en%
% Bar count 6
\xbar
\pnotes{3.46}\qlp{'b}\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\cl{'c}\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\pcaesura00\qu{'a}\qu a\en%
% Bar count 7
\alaligne
\endeq%
\pnotes{3.46}\spread{-6}\qup g\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\cu{'a}\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\pcaesura00\qu f\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\ibl1{'a}2\qb1a\tbl1\qb1c\en%
% Bar count 8
\xbar
\pnotes{2.00}\ibu1{'b}{-1}\qb1c\qb1b\qb1a\tbu1\qb1{`g}\en%
\pnotes{4.00}\pcaesura00\hu{'a}\en%
% Bar count 9
\xbar
\pnotes{4.00}%
\pmxlyr{Kuu, s\"{a}-rav kuu, h\~{o}-be-da-ne kuu uj-ub o-ma val-gus-voos.}%
\hl{'c}\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\qu{'a}\qu{`f}\en%
% Bar count 10
\alaligne
\pnotes{4.00}\spread{-6}\pcaesura00\hu c\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\ibu1{'a}0\qb1{`f}\qb1{'c}\qb1a\tbu1\qb1{`f}\en%
% Bar count 11
\xbar
\pnotes{4.00}\pcaesura00\hu c\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\ibu1e{-1}\qb1f\qb1e\qb1d\tbu1\qb1c\en%
% Bar count 12
\xbar
\pnotes{2.83}\qu b\qu c\en%
\pnotes{4.00}\hu f\en%
\Endpiece
\vfill\eject\endmuflex
\bye
```

Even bigger problems arise after editing the script as suggested above (compare end of post). At first all the notes are stacked in about no space, then trying to run `musixflx` on it, as suggested [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373446/musixtex-problem-with-format), throws the error message: "File not found: jobname.mx1". So I am trying to run etex on the script, which on its part can't read the `\documentclass` and stuff...

How to break this vicious circle?

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % for characters in lyrics
\usepackage{musixtex}

\input musixtex
\input pmx
\setmaxslurs{24}\setmaxinstruments{24}%
\normalmusicsize%
%\nopagenumbers
\begin{document}
\tracingstats=2\relax
\hsize=524pt
\vsize740pt
\def\nbinstruments{1}
\setstaffs11
\setclef10
\setname1{ }
\generalsignature{-1}%
\generalmeter\meterC%
\parindent 0pt
\elemskip1pt\afterruleskip1.000pt\beforeruleskip0pt\relax
\stafftopmarg0pt\staffbotmarg5\Interligne\interstaff{10}\relax
\nostartrule
\readmod{Saabund}
\nobarnumbers%
\input musixlyr %
\startmuflex\startpiece\addspace\afterruleskip%
\global\parskip 0pt plus 12\Interligne minus 99\Interligne%
\def\upstrut{\znotes&\zcharnote{\upamt}{~}\en}%
\znotes\zcharnote{16}{\titles{2.0}{}{0}%
{Saabund on j\"{a}lle \"{o}\"{o}}{2.0}{}{0}}\en%
% Bar count 1
\starteq%
\pnotes{4.00}%
\pmxlyr{Saa-bund on j\"{a}-lle \"{o}\"{o}, mis mei-le t\"{a}h-te-de vaik-set ra-hu toob.}\spread{-6}%
\hu f\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\qu f\qu f\en%
% Bar count 2
\xbar
\pnotes{3.46}\qup g\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\cu{'a}\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\pcaesura00\qu f\qu f\en%
% Bar count 3
\xbar
\pnotes{3.46}\qlp{'b}\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\cl{'c}\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\qu{'a}\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\ibu1f2\qb1f\tbu1\qb1{'a}\en%
% Bar count 4
\alaligne
\pnotes{2.00}\spread{-6}\ibu1g{-1}\qb1{'a}\qb1{`g}\qb1f\tbu1\qb1e\en%
\pnotes{4.00}\pcaesura00\hu f\en%
% Bar count 5
\xbar
\pnotes{4.00}%
\pmxlyr{L\~{o}pp-e-nud p\"{a}ev-a-t\"{o}\"{o} ja puh-ke-aeg ta-sa v\"{a}rs-keid j\~{o}u-de koob.}%
\hu{'a}\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\qu{'a}\qu a\en%
% Bar count 6
\xbar
\pnotes{3.46}\qlp{'b}\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\cl{'c}\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\pcaesura00\qu{'a}\qu a\en%
% Bar count 7
\alaligne
\endeq%
\pnotes{3.46}\spread{-6}\qup g\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\cu{'a}\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\pcaesura00\qu f\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\ibl1{'a}2\qb1a\tbl1\qb1c\en%
% Bar count 8
\xbar
\pnotes{2.00}\ibu1{'b}{-1}\qb1c\qb1b\qb1a\tbu1\qb1{`g}\en%
\pnotes{4.00}\pcaesura00\hu{'a}\en%
% Bar count 9
\xbar
\pnotes{4.00}%
\pmxlyr{Kuu, s\"{a}-rav kuu, h\~{o}-be-da-ne kuu uj-ub o-ma val-gus-voos.}%
\hl{'c}\en%
\pnotes{2.83}\qu{'a}\qu{`f}\en%
% Bar count 10
\alaligne
\pnotes{4.00}\spread{-6}\pcaesura00\hu c\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\ibu1{'a}0\qb1{`f}\qb1{'c}\qb1a\tbu1\qb1{`f}\en%
% Bar count 11
\xbar
\pnotes{4.00}\pcaesura00\hu c\en%
\pnotes{2.00}\ibu1e{-1}\qb1f\qb1e\qb1d\tbu1\qb1c\en%
% Bar count 12
\xbar
\pnotes{2.83}\qu b\qu c\en%
\pnotes{4.00}\hu f\en%
\Endpiece
\vfill\eject\endmuflex
%\bye
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could someone add a `PMX` tag, please?