# MusiXTeX problem with musixflx

Tags: musixtex

I try to compile my score (prepared with `MusiXTeX` package) by following the three-pass system as described [here](http://icking-music-archive.org/software/musixtex/musixdoc.pdf) (pt. 1.3). Accordingly, I run `etex` on my .tex file, then I run `musixflx` on the .mx1 file created in the previous step and then I run `etex` again. The problem is, it yields no result (I mean the pdf output remains unchanged). I think that it may have something to do with the fact that the .mx2 file produced by executing the second pass (running `musixflx`) seems to be empty. I use TeXStudio editor and TeXLive distribution.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{musixtex,etex}

\begin{document}
    \begin{music}
        \nobarnumbers
        \setstaffs1{2}
        \setclef1\bass
        \generalsignature{-1}
        
        \startextract

            \notesp
            {\zql{`f}}\qu{`h} {\zql{f}}\qu{h} {\zql{f}}\qu{h} {\zw f}\isluru0i\hu{i*} \tslur0{'c}\hu{c*} \qu{`f*} \caesura
            \wh{f**} {\lql f}\qu{g} {\zql f}\qu{h} {\zhl f}\hu{i*} {\zwh f}\wh{i**}
            | 
            \qu{fff} {\lw f}\ibsluru0g\hu{g*} \tslur0h\hu{h*} \qu{f*} \caesura
            \wh{f**} {\lql f}\qu{g} {\zql f}\qu{h} {\zhl f}\hu{i*} {\zwh f}\wh{i**}
            \en\bar

            \notesp
            {\zwqq{c}}\wqq{`f****} {\zhu{i}}\hl{c*} {\zw{h}}\wh{f**}
            | 
            {\zwqq{f}}\wqq{h****} {\zhl{e}}\hu{g*} {\zw{d}}\wh{f**}
            \en
            \Endpiece
    
        \zendextract
    \end{music}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Colud add, please, your `\documentclass` and the other packages?

Comment: Sorry, I omitted them as I copied the code. I've just added it by editing the original post.

Comment: If I run your example, the produced `mx1` file contains just two lines: first line `83`, second line `* 0 0`. Running `musixflx` with the `d` flag, I get the message “Corrupted apflx.mx1” (`apflx` is the file name I used for your example).

Comment: Thank you. There's apparently something wrong with my example - I tried processing this example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373446/musixtex-problem-with-format/373447#373447 with the three-pass system and it worked perfectly for me. At least I got to know I need to fix something in the example itself ;)

Comment: You can compile your document  via  `pdflatex document.tex`...

Comment: @A.P. Don't worry :-).

Answer (score 1):

I tried your sample with  `latex`  `musixflx` and `latex` process, for me it seems the sample itself produces no `.mx2` file.

The [documentation](http://icking-music-archive.org/software/musixtex/musixdoc.pdf) says the best example is the documentation itself, why not you have a try?

Here, I attach to you a useful tool `makefile`, it could be super easy with command line.

```
# Author: c275633094@gmail.com
# Date: 05-04-2018
# MusiXTeX musixdoc tutorial example makefile
## First, set the main filename = YOUR_TEX_FILE_NAME_WITHOUT_.TEX
# $ make, to run commands in this file
# $ make read, to read the pdf file
# $ make clean, to clean the inter file

filename=YOUR_TEX_FILE_NAME

all:
    latex ${filename}
    musixflx ${filename}
    bibtex ${filename}||true
    latex ${filename}
    makeindex ${filename}
    latex ${filename}
    latex ${filename}
    dvips -e0 ${filename}
    ps2pdf ${filename}.ps

read:
    evince ${filename}.pdf &

oread:
    okular ${filename}.pdf

clean:
    -rm -f *.aux
    -rm -f *.ps
    -rm -f *.dvi
    -rm -f *.idx
    -rm -f *.ilg
    -rm -f *.ind
    -rm -f *.mx1
    -rm -f *.mx2
    -rm -f *.log
    -rm -f *.toc
    -rm -f *.bbl
    -rm -f *.blg
    -rm -f *.out
    -rm -f make/bib
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the Visual Studio Code for just one click compile using latexmkrc file:

```
$xelatex = 'internal musixlatex %R %O %S';
push @generated_exts,"mx2";
push @generated_exts,"mx1";

sub musixlatex {
   my $root = shift;
   # Define root filename for the mx1 and mx2 files
   # Note that $aux_dir1 includes directory separator
   #      and it equals $out_dir1 if only the out_dir is set.
   my $mx = "$aux_dir1$root";
   my @args = @_;
   if ( $pass{$rule} <= 1 ) { 
      print "======= FIRST PASS: Deleting '$mx.mx2' =======\n";
      unlink "$mx.mx2"; 
      print "====   Generating '$mx.mx1' then '$mx.mx2' ===\n";
      my $ret = system( "xelatex @args" );
      if ($ret) { return $ret; }
      $ret = system( "musixflx $mx" );
      if ($ret) { return $ret; }
   }
   return system( "xelatex @args" );
}
```

Also, I reconfigured your file as follow:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixlyr}
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras


\begin{document}
    \begin{music}
        \nobarnumbers
        \setstaffs1{2}
        \setclef1\bass
        \generalsignature{-1}
        \startextract
            \notesp
            {\zql{`f}}\qu{`h} {\zql{f}}\qu{h} {\zql{f}}\qu{h} {\zw f}\isluru0i\hu{i*} \tslur0{'c}\hu{c*} \qu{`f*} \caesura
            \wh{f**} {\lql f}\qu{g} {\zql f}\qu{h} {\zhl f}\hu{i*} {\zwh f}\wh{i**}
            | 
            \qu{fff} {\lw f}\ibsluru0g\hu{g*} \tslur0h\hu{h*} \qu{f*} \caesura
            \wh{f**} {\lql f}\qu{g} {\zql f}\qu{h} {\zhl f}\hu{i*} {\zwh f}\wh{i**}
            \en\bar

            \notesp
            {\zwqq{c}}\wqq{`f****} {\zhu{i}}\hl{c*} {\zw{h}}\wh{f**}
            | 
            {\zwqq{f}}\wqq{h****} {\zhl{e}}\hu{g*} {\zw{d}}\wh{f**}
            \setdoubleBAR\en\setdoubleBAR
        \endextract
    \end{music}
\end{document}
```

The output is as follow:

[image: output]